# Elixir reduce to find first available date in range with Timex

Tags: recursion, elixir, reduce, timex

I have a list of dates that represent bookings for a room. I want to be able to find out where the first available day is in the date range.

```
# let us assume today is the 1st Feb
today = #DateTime<2019-02-01 00:00:00Z>

# here are our booked days
booked_days = [
  #DateTime<2019-02-08 00:00:00Z>, 
  #DateTime<2019-02-05 00:00:00Z>, 
  #DateTime<2019-02-03 00:00:00Z>, 
  #DateTime<2019-02-02 00:00:00Z>
]
```

What we’d like to have returned here is `#DateTime<2019-02-04 00:00:00Z>` because it’s the first available date.

I’ve looked at doing something like this using `Enum.reduce_while` in combination with `Timex.Interval`, but with no luck as `reduce_while` seems to return the interval after the first call.

```
today = Timex.now() |> Timex.beginning_of_day()

first_available =
  Enum.reduce_while(booked_days, today, fn from, until ->
    interval = Timex.Interval.new(from: from, until: until)
    duration = Timex.Interval.duration(interval, :days)

    if duration <= 1,
      do: {:cont, from},
      else: {:halt, interval}
  end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can sort the dates in ascending order.
Then iterate the dates and check for empty intervals between dates and return the date if the date is greater than or equal to from date.

```
sorted_dates = Enum.sort(booked_days , fn a, b -> Timex.compare(a, b, :days)<0 end) 
get_next_booking_date(sorted_dates, today)
```

```
def get_next_booking_date([], _from_date) do
    nil
end

def get_next_booking_date([_last_booking_date], _from_date) do
   # You can add a day  to last booking date and return that date or return nil depending on your need
   # Timex.add(_last_booking_date, Timex.Duration.from_days(1))
   nil
end

def get_next_booking_date([next, next2 | rest], from_date) do

    # add a day to the current day and check if there's an empty interval and that the empty slot is greater than from date

    temp_next = Timex.add(next, Timex.Duration.from_days(1))        

    if Timex.compare(temp_next, next2, :days) == -1  and Timex.compare(temp_next, from_date) >= 0 do
      temp_next
    else
      get_next_booking_date([next2 | rest], from)
    end
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `[next| [ next2 | _]=rest]`might be written in more concise manner: `[next, next2 | rest]` (and use `[next2 | rest]` below instead of `rest`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Yeah that's cleaner. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer by @Badu is correct, I’d post the solution with the desired [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce_while/3).

Elixir nowadays has great built-in support for dates in the first place, so I doubt I follow why would you need `Timex`. And you’d better deal with *dates* not with *date times* when it comes to *booked days* (unless you allow pay-per-hour bookings.) But if you want `DateTime`s, here you go:

```rb
# Please next time make your input available to copy-paste
[today | booked_days] =
  [1, 8, 5, 3, 2]
  |> Enum.map(& {{2019, 02, &1}, {0, 0, 0}}
  |> NaiveDateTime.from_erl!()
  |> DateTime.from_naive!("Etc/UTC"))

booked_days
|> Enum.sort(& Date.compare(&1, &2) == :lt)
|> Enum.reduce_while(today, fn d, curr ->
  if Date.diff(d, curr) == 1,
    do: {:cont, d},
    else: {:halt, DateTime.add(curr, 3600 * 24)}
end)
#⇒ #DateTime<2019-02-04 00:00:00Z>
```

Comment: Thank you! I’m still having trouble getting this working as I get a `function DateTime.add/2 is undefined or private`. What does it mean in the first part where we have `{2019, 02, &1}` — is this hard coded to only work with February 2019?

Comment: What version of Elixir do you use? [`DateTime.add/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DateTime.html#add/4) was introduced in `1.8`. In the first part, we build the input to check the implementation since you did not provide the data to test. In real life, you just have both `today` and `booked_days` on hand.

Comment: Okay great it works now! Another quick question (so I know in future)… what is the best way to provide Elixir dates when asking a question on here?

Comment: Whatever code that can be copy-pasted into `iex` to avoid the necessity to produce the data ourselves. Like the mine above. Or just erlang tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a version without Timex

Create an array of elements with `[[1st date, 2nd date], [2nd date, 3rd date], .. [ith, (i-1)st]...]` (using zip by offset 1) then find the position where the two differ by more than 1 day.

```rb
defmodule DateGetter do

  def get_next_date(booked_dates) do

    sorted = Enum.sort(booked_dates)

    date = sorted
    |> Enum.zip(Enum.drop sorted, 1) # or use Enum.chunk_every for large sizes
    |> Enum.find(fn {d1, d2} -> DateTime.diff(d2, d1) > 86400 end)

    case date do
      nil ->
        {:error, "no dates found"}
      {date1, date2} ->
        (DateTime.to_unix(date1) + 86400) |> DateTime.from_unix
    end
  end
end

# Sample input:
booked_dates =
  [2,5,3,8]
  |> Enum.map(fn d ->
    DateTime.from_iso8601("2015-01-0#{d} 01:00:00Z")
    |> elem(1)
  end)   

DateGetter.get_next_date booked_dates
#> {:ok, #DateTime<2015-01-04 01:00:00Z>}
```

Comment: Use [`Enum.chunk_every(list, 2, 1)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#chunk_every/4) instead of `drop |> zip`.

Comment: `chunk_every` vs `drop |> zip` is just personal preference in this case. And handling the logic of whether last date is chosen would be in calling function. This function is just limited to finding an available date in the range.

Comment: It’s not just personal preference, try to benchmark on the list having 1G elements.

Comment: I doubt there will be that many elements in this case, but i will add a comment there

Comment: Well, good habits are good habits :) What you need is chunks, and anybody who is to read the code later would immediately understand the intent of `chunk_every` but might stumble on `drop |> zip`.

Comment: You're right :), I still think of drop and zip as primitives that most languages would have. But drop wouldn't have to create an intermediate array in case of immutable arrays right? I wonder if there is a performance diff and where. Will investigate

Comment: _Sidenote:_ it’s a list, not an array. And no, [`drop` would not create an intermediate list](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/0558e7c92a93b9c7952464388504a437b9600875/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2898-L2900). This is because it’s an immutable _linked list_. Arrays cannot be sliced without copying.

Comment: Right, but it would be unsafe to do this if original list was mutable.

Comment: Sorry.. my arrays and lists had become interchangeable thanks to javascript :( :sigh: